Ejecutar archvio Java
Buen día, soy nuevo en programación, estoy estudiando java y el ambiente eclipse, ya descargue y configure las dos apps, pero al intentar abrir con java un archivo .java que descargue desde mi plataforma de estudio me sale el siguiente anuncio, agradezco si alguien sabe que debo hacer.


¿Mismo caso? Además, el código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato. Por último, Java no es un lenguaje de programación de bajo nivel, y Java != Javascript :) Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal con jar

Yo te recomendaría primero verificar si tienes instalado el JDK de java en la ventana de comandos (cmd) con los siguientes comandos.
java -version
javac -version
En dado caso de que te parezca la versión debes dirigirte a la ruta donde se encuentra el programa y colocar los siguientes comandos
javac nombre_del_programa.java (este primer comando te ayudara a compilar el programa y si no tiene errores no te saldrá ninguna advertencia)
java nombre_del_programa (con este comando ejecutaras el programa)
Nota busca que el programa tenga una estructura como la siguiente ya que esta es la estructura de la clase principal
public class Programa {

      public static void main(String[] args){
         (bloque de código)
      }

}

Con eso ya estarías listo para compilar todos los códigos posibles.
En caso de no tener la versión de java te recomiendo que veas esta foto de parte de la empresa Alura Latam que son las instrucciones para instalarlo y añadirlo al path del sistema para ejecutarlo.

